# Inviso Installation Error with index_cluster_stats.py

Tags: python, hadoop

Inviso [Website](http://github.com/Netflix/inviso)

I install Inviso for visualizing Hadoop Job performance following the README.md.
When it comes to step 6 with the command " **python index_cluster_stats.py** ", it fails with the following. 
I am confused with the port 9026, it just shows up suddenly, I do not know when it get configured. Should I change the port?

```
ERROR:inviso.cluster:Error processing: cluster_1
ERROR:inviso.cluster:HTTPConnectionPool(host='taoran1', port=9026): Max retries exceeded with url: /ws/v1/cluster/apps?state=RUNNING (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "index_cluster_stats.py", line 90, in index_stats
index_apps(es, cluster, info)
File "index_cluster_stats.py", line 17, in index_apps
apps = requests.get('http:// %s:%s/ws/v1/cluster/apps?state=RUNNING' % (cluster.host, '9026'), headers = {'ACCEPT':'application/json'}).json().get('apps')
File "/home/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/home/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/home/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='taoran1', port=9026): Max retries exceeded with url: /ws/v1/cluster/apps?state=RUNNING (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Also, when conducted the command "**python jes.py**", it came up with the followings, I do not know whether it matters for the Error above.

```
INFO:inviso-monitor:Publishing event: (cluster_1) job_1413958950234_0008 2014-10-23T02:37:35+00:00
INFO:inviso-handler:Processing 1 events
WARNING:inviso-handler:No trace info available for hdfs://taoran1:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2014/10/23/000000/job_1413958950234_0008-1414031808636-hadoop-QuasiMonteCarlo-1414031855566-4-1-SUCCEEDED-default-1414031818339.jhist
INFO:inviso-handler:Indexing 1 documents
INFO:inviso-handler:Events complete.
```